# Long press action clue/indicator

Tags: interaction-design, touch-screen, mouse, long-press

On a desktop and touch devices, I'd like to know is there is a way to tell the user that some control could be clicked (one action) ***and long pressed*** (another action)?

**Real-world example**:

- We have column chart

[image]

- Tap performed on column 2007 (single selection)

[image]

- Tap performed on column 2009 (single selection)

[image]

- Long press performed on column 2010 (single selection)

[image]

Current situation is that user **doesn't know** that chart has possibility to multi-select columns (perform long press). How to indicate that it is possible?

Comment: Is the long press possibility the only possibility of the button, or can the user also perform a short press?

Comment: @NGAFD yes, click is also possible (e.g on click items in a list behave like radio button group, but on long press we can select several items like checkbox group).

Comment: Take a look at [Material design - Selection Patterns](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/selection.html#selection-item-selection).

Comment: @NGAFD example added to a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the bars have **both** a click and a long press, i reckon there are a couple of ways to acheive this.

- Write a small **info note** at the end informing the users about the long press
- Give some **visual feedback** , like a small circle filling up as the user makes contact with the page/touches the page.
- one more form of visual feedback : **start 'filling' the bar with color** when user makes contact. click will make the bar fill up instantly, when that is seen . i guess the user will make an attempt to fill it up slowly, i.e long press .

  - in the above scenario, once user has long pressed, i'd recommend elevating the selected bar above the others to make sure it was selected via long-press or use a different fill color.

We used the last scenario for an app where user had this same confusion , but then again those were cards and not bars. But i hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Changing the color of the column may be too little for the user to know that he have selected something.
Along with the color change, you could display a top toolbar showing how many items the user selected along with the option to cancel selection and other specific actions.

Someting like that:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFJGC3.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I hope it helps :)